# How can i model "Conveyors" breakdown time in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

1-I am modeling a production line in Anylogic that has a group of Conveyors. Each Conveyor has it's own failures and breakdowns. How can i Create a pool of Resources from the existing Library "Conveyor".

2-Is there any way to attach "Conveyor" to "Resource pool"

I tried Conveyor in Material Handling list but i does not have Resource set so that i can attach a Resource pool

Answer (score 0):

You may want to "agent-ify" your conveyors: Create a custom agent type `MyConveyor` that has 1 conveyor and some info on downtimes, etc.

Flag these are "Use as resources" in its properties.

Then, you can use them as resources in resource-pools.

However: This probably won't solve your immediate issue right away as it is a bit advanced.

Comment: First Thanks for you Answer. 

Creating a custom agent from "Agent Type" named "MyConveyor" will allow me to add it to the resource pool. However it will not allow me to link the Class "Conveyor" to the resource pool.

This way i will have 2 agents, and the one that i need to model it's break downs (class "Conveyor" ) with it's length and speed, are not attached to the resource pool. 

Is there any way to link class "Conveyors" to break downs?  

Thanks

Comment: You need to do this yourself by accessing the actual Conveyor within the MyConveyor agent type

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sQWL.jpg)what you can do is to generate a failure token (Failure agent) that is associated to a conveyor (has a conveyor as a parameter)

Then you change the speed of the conveyor to 0

```
conveyor.setMaxSpeed(0,MPS);
```

Then the token will seize a resource and the resource will act accordingly

finally when the resource is released, you change the max speed to its original

Comment: if i understood right it should be
1-create agent type called failure token
2-attach it to class conveyor
3-modify the speed of the class conveyor as shown
4-attach the agent type called failure token to the resource pool 
that should attach the resource pool to the class conveyor?

Comment: you create a Failure agent, add_Failure(conveyor) and then you send to an enter block that will then be connected to a seize block which will seize the operator that needs to fix the conveyor...